# ODP.NET connections being prematurely closed (or closed twice?) in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: .net, oracle, vb.net, odp.net

I have a problem where, inconsistently, an ODP.NET connection will report back that it's closed when I expect it to be open. Somewhere in the lifetime of my object, which opens the connection, it's getting closed, even though the `.Close()` is only called as part of the `Dispose` method. Notably, it only seems to happen when used in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

I have a list of objects that need validating which is done in a Parallel.ForEach like this:

```vb
Parallel.ForEach(ls,
                 Sub(rec)
                     rec.Validate()
                 End Sub)
```

Within the `.Validate` method  I call this:

```vb
Dim values As New DbValues
Using sql As New SqlLog(strOraConn)
    sql.Connect()
    values = sql.GetValues(id, params)
End Using

'Do a bunch of calculations on values
```

This `SqlLog` object is essentially a wrapper around an Oracle package. The constructor and `.Connect()`, and `GetValues` methods look like this:

```
Private _Connection As New OracleConnection()
Private _Transaction As OracleTransaction

Public Sub New(ByVal OracleConnectionString As String)
    _Connection.ConnectionString = OracleConnectionString
End Sub

Public Sub Connect()
    If _Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
        _Connection.Open()
        _Transaction = _Connection.BeginTransaction()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub GetValues(ByVal ID As Integer, ByVal params As Params)
    Using Command As OracleCommand = _Connection.CreateCommand()
        'Bunch of boilerplate connection/parameters code
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

When done, the stored procedure `log.Disconnect` needs to be called, which is done in the `.Disconnect()` method of `SqlLog` object:

```vb
Public Sub Disconnect()
    Using Command As OracleCommand = _Connection.CreateCommand()
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Command.CommandText = "log.Disconnect"
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    _Transaction.Commit()
    _Connection.Close()
End Sub
```

This `Disconnect()` method is public, but in my code it is not directly called.

In order to take advantage of `Using`, the `IDisposable` implementation calls this `Disconnect()` method:

```vb
Private disposedValue As Boolean

Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    If Not disposedValue Then
        If disposing Then
            Disconnect()
        End If
    End If
    disposedValue = True
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Dispose(True)
End Sub
```

The problem is that occasionally, when calling `Disconnect()` the error `Connection must be open` exception is thrown.

This doesn't happen every time, and indeed only seems to happen when used in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

My thought is that it's related to ODP.NET ConnectionPooling, but I haven't a clue what could be going on, or how to further investigate.

EDIT: Worth also mentioning that this is happening with 'Validate Connection=True' set in the connection string.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

Comment: Long time ago Microsoft came with Enterprise library data blocks. The problem with that was that it used Microsoft-supplied providers. But if you adapt it to use Native providers, generally, that code should be your data layer. You're creating some kind stateful layer, which does not need to be stateful. You packed data access and logging into 1. What if you have an issue with data access? Then your log is useless. May be use some async queue to log messages, then use some service to write then to DB. In your current design, one pulls down the other.

Comment: `You packed data access and logging into 1`. I think you're inferring a lot about what this is doing from the naming of some objects. This is simply running a query and iterating over the results. For each record in the result set it's grabbing some additional data and running validation on that. The problem is that accessing that additional data (`SqlLog`) in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop runs into issues as described. If you have a better example of how to do what I've shown, please do post as an answer - I'd gladly have a look.

Comment: Here is what I read on oracle command and connection *"**Thread Safety** All public static methods are thread-safe, although instance methods do not guarantee thread safety."* This means that if you paralleling, you need to call a method that does not share command, connection etc. Each parallel execution should open its own connection and execute, and then close the connection

Comment: `Each parallel execution should open its own connection and execute, and then close the connection` That's what I'm doing. Each `SqlLog` instance is created and disposed and creates it's own connection. Which is basically the entire problem, the connection is getting closed by something else...

Comment: There is a thing called `CommandBehavior` It can be set to close the connection on call completion. Try specifying a specific behavior